# XAML can't see a class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My xaml goes like this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Helpers:EnumHelper x:Key="EnumHelper" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

And my class is defined like this:

```
namespace MyProj.View.UserControlHelpers {
    public class EnumHelper { }
}
```

The error I get is this:

> The name "EnumHelper" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyProj.View.UserControlHelpers".

I've cleaned this project from the studio, then I've deleted every file in bin and obj subdirectories, I've even changed class name, still without success - I'm still getting this error.

EDIT:

My xaml headers are lik this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProj.View.Partials.TableWindow.Columns"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
             xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
             xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:MyProj.View.UserControlHelpers"
             xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:MyProj.Model"
             xmlns:ModelHelpers="clr-namespace:MyProj.Model.Helpers"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
```

Comment: I don't get it. What do you want me to do?

Comment: Show your XAML header with all attributes describing XML namespaces and imported CLR namespaces.

Comment: When did you get the error message? If you get it during authoring your XAML in the editor, rather than compiling your project, try to (re)build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class namespace is

```
MadMin.View.UserControlHelpers
```

but you refer to it in xaml as

```
MyProj.View.UserControlHelpers
```

Comment: How can this have solved the problem, if the namespace names were the same all along, as stated in the updated version of the question?

Comment: Actually the namespace names were not the same - on one computer (where this code worked) - they were the same and on the other machine (where this didn't work) they weren't.